# Find lowest value and coresponding code on asingle query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user table as follows

```
id   name      age

1    John      21

2.   Mathan    23

3.   Raj       21

4.   Manoj     50

5    Krishnan  91
```

**I want to find minimum age and its corresponding name. How can I do it with rails?**

Can I do it in a single query?

Note: More than one names can have single age.

Comment: What is your expected out put from current data?

Comment: I want to find minimum age and its corresponding name

Comment: Here minimum age is 21 and that age contains John and Raj means both name do you want?

Comment: @Sadikhasan - The o/p is to be like [{"John"=>"21"},{"Raj"=>"21"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you want to do it in a single query ?

If you can write 2 queries, I think you can just write :

```
User.where age: User.minimum(:age)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select age, group_concat(name) from table group by age order by age asc limit 1
```

You will need to process the results later on in ruby, but this gives all you need in one single query. Also i am assuming mysql, so might differ on other rdbms.

Answer (score 0):

It gives exact output in mysql that you want try this

```
SELECT concat("[",name," ",age,"]") AS name
FROM TABLE
WHERE age =
    (SELECT min(age)
     FROM TABLE);
```

Comment: what you have added d at first was correct. I need rails console query. But it gave only one entry. The minimum age which was first

Comment: I give mysql query you have to convert in rails. Is it work or not in mysql?